# Nothing on right border of screen in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

I upgraded to Windows 8. When I have a window maximized (eg. a browser) on the desktop, there is a vertical scroll bar.

I can use a mouse to scroll up and down by clicking the scroll bar, and dragging it up and down.

However, if I try to click on the right-most pixel (column 1 pixel wide), the scroll bar doesn't work.

If the scroll bar is not there, what is there? When I click there, nothing happens. It can't be the charms bar, because it only shows up when the mouse is on the top right/bottom right corner.

If it has no purpose, how can I get rid of this behaviour? Obviously when I try to drag the scroll bar, I get trapped on the right-most pixel column a lot.

Comment: Ok, I worked out why. It seems I managed to get two graphics card drivers to run at the same time, so my computer thought I had two monitors (only the one on the right didn't have an actual monitor to display on). I am now uninstalling everything and reinstalling my graphics card drivers - hopefully it will fix it.

Comment: Instead of reinstalling drivers you can try this: right-click on an empty desktop, choose *Screen resolution*, then click *Detect* in the upper-right corner. It should reduce the number of monitors to the actual number.

Comment: that doesn't work, because I have am using the AMD reference driver on top of the HP drivers to get it working. I disabled the 2nd screen, using Display desktop only on 1 setting.

Comment: So after removing the 2nd desktop, I find that Chrome and most other applications are fixed. However, for some reason, notepad still has this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This 1-pixel-bar isn't there for me, tested with Firefox and Internet Explorer, both desktop and <s>Metro</s> Modern UI.

Most likely, a process you are running is showing something there. Try running Process Explorer and dragging its "target cross" to the right of your screen to see which process holds that object.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, where do I find the process explorer?

Comment: You can download Process Explorer directly from Microsoft here: http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896653